# Does organic chemistry somehow defy the periodic table?

Tags: organic-chemistry, periodic-table

My physics lecturer was introducing the idea of what a Theory of Everything was, and said something like this:

> Other sciences have their own theories of everything too, fundamental axioms from which everything else can be derived from. In mathematics, we have ZFC, and well, the entire framework of abstract mathematics and axiomatic systems. Even in Chemistry, all of modern chemistry can be derived from the periodic table and the laws of atomic structure. **Well ... except for two words: Organic Chem.**

Is this true? Can organic chemistry somehow not be derived within the framework of the periodic table?

Comment: He/she was probably just kidding, it's very common for physical chemists (equivalently, physicists) to jokingly talk down towards organic chemists (and vice versa).

Comment: While some organic chemists are especially ignorant of anything beyond their art of synthetic work, actually nowhere in chemistry is it possible to accurately predict really *new* things. In hindsight, everything has however been explainable once the theoretical chemist (sometimes the same person) sat down and tried to. Good thing, too. Only logical knowledge can be handed down. Intuition and a fair amount of guesswork only work at the foremost front of science.

Answer (score 2):

While all chemistry is unified because all chemical compounds are made from things in the periodic table, that isn't like mathematics and much of physics. In these sciences many important complexities are derivable from a simple set of axioms.

Some chemistry is simple to derive or deduce from the periodic table but not all of it. The electronic properties of iron atoms tell you a lot about many iron compounds; the location of alkali metals in the table tells us a lot about their common properties.

But carbon is odd. The properties of simple compounds follow simple periodic patterns. But there are more organic compounds (consisting of carbon skeletons, usually with C-C bonds) than all other chemical put together. The complexity and variety of carbon chemistry is almost unfathomably large. None of this is obvious or predictable from the periodic table. You can't deduce the enormous variety from the simple properties of carbon atoms or anything given in the periodic table.

That is probably the sort of distinction your lecturer was aiming at.

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible to know exactly what your professor was implying, but one idea might be that life itself is a mystery. Generally organic chemistry is associated with living things that use a multitude of carbon compounds. Chemists know how organic reactions in general will proceed but we don't have a solid understanding as to how life itself can be created.